# How to relate more than two tables in greenDAO ORM?

Tags: android, greendao

I am working on an application in which I want to save a list of list. I save all the data perfectly but when I fetch the data this come, but not in order.

For example, I want to save a book which has many chapters and a chapter have many paragraphs and each paragraph have a set of question and a question have one question one answer and four option.

I made the schema for all table like chapters, paragraphs,question and also relate them very well but I when I save the data this is saved in the separate table but not relatively. like chapter list contains only chapter name and paragraph list only contain paragraphs and similarly question.

So my question is this how to relate them? For example, I have a list of books which contain chapters and so on.
Thanks in advance.

```
Entity course = schema.addEntity("Course");
course.setTableName("Courses");
course.addIdProperty().primaryKey().autoincrement();
course.addStringProperty("course_name").notNull();
course.addStringProperty("course_id").notNull();

//chapter schema
Entity chapter = schema.addEntity("ChapterList");
chapter.setTableName("Chapters");
chapter.addIdProperty().primaryKey().autoincrement();
chapter.addStringProperty("chapter_name").notNull();

//relation chapter to course
Property chapterDate = chapter.addDateProperty("cahpter_add_date").getProperty();
Property courseId = chapter.addLongProperty("course_id").getProperty();
chapter.addToOne(course,courseId);

//relation course to chapter
ToMany courseToChapter = course.addToMany(chapter, courseId);
courseToChapter.setName("chapter_list");
courseToChapter.orderAsc(chapterDate);
```

This is the code for table creation and this code saving data.

```
public static void getCourseFromBackend(ParseObject p) {
    DaoSession daoSession = WWApplication.getDaoSession();
    CourseDao courseDao = daoSession.getCourseDao();
    Course course = new Course();

    String courseId = p.getString(Constants.ParseKeys.COURSE_ID);
    course.setCourse_name(p.getString(Constants.ParseKeys.COURSE_NAME));
    course.setCourse_id(courseId);
    List<ParseObject> chapterList = p.getList(Constants.ParseKeys.CHAPTER_LIST);
    if (chapterList != null) {
        for (ParseObject bChapter : chapterList) {
            saveChapterFromBackend(bChapter, course, courseId);
        }
    }
    courseDao.insert(course);
}

public static void saveChapterFromBackend(ParseObject object, Course course, String courseId){
    DaoSession daoSession = WWApplication.getDaoSession();
    ChapterListDao chapterListDao = daoSession.getChapterListDao();
    ChapterList chapter = new ChapterList();

    String chapName = object.getString(Constants.ParseKeys.CHAPTER_NAME);
    chapter.setChapter_name(chapName);

    chapter.setCourse(course);
    chapter.setCourse_id(course.getId());
    chapterListDao.insert(chapter);
}
```

But when I retrieve data `chapterList` is null. Where is the problem: saving or fetching?

Comment: Provide the relevant parts of your code.

Comment: @AllanPereira i edited my question and provide a few part code.